# Transform a dataframe to matrix format by group id in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, plyr

I'm trying to convert a `data.frame` object into `matrix` format by some group id using the `dlply` function, but the resulting object clearly is not of `matrix` format.
Could anyone point out what's going on here?

```css
library(plyr)

#load the data
export <- readRDS(url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/7nn4kcdbsiteplj/export.rds?dl=1"))

export_mat <- dlply(export,.(reporter_iso), fun = as.matrix)

str(export_mat)

List of 161
 $ afg:'data.frame':    161 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ reporter_iso: chr [1:161] "afg" "afg" "afg" "afg" ...
  ..$ partner_iso : chr [1:161] "afg" "ago" "alb" "are" ...
  ..$ cong_pct    : num [1:161] 0 0 0 0.0915 0 ...
  ..$ cag_pct     : num [1:161] 0 0 0 0.0297 0 ...
  ..$ ig_pct      : num [1:161] 0 0 0 0.049 0 ...
  ..$ rm_pct      : num [1:161] 0 0 0 0.83 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "vars")= chr "reporter_iso"
 $ ago:'data.frame':    161 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ reporter_iso: chr [1:161] "ago" "ago" "ago" "ago" ...
  ..$ partner_iso : chr [1:161] "afg" "ago" "alb" "are" ...
  ..$ cong_pct    : num [1:161] 0 0 0 0.203 0 ...
  ..$ cag_pct     : num [1:161] 0 0 0 0.698 0 ...
  ..$ ig_pct      : num [1:161] 0 0 0 0.0148 0 ...
  ..$ rm_pct      : num [1:161] 0 0 0 0.0842 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "vars")= chr "reporter_iso"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong argument name, try this:

```
export_mat <- dlply(export,.(reporter_iso), .fun = as.matrix)
```

Comment: I tested via R 4.0.2 and plyr v1.8.6

Comment: Many thanks! Strangely, the `dlply` function turn the numeric values inside the cells into "character."

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can use `by` :

```
export_mat <- by(export, export$reporter_iso, as.matrix)
```

Or `split` + `lapply` :

```
export_mat <- lapply(split(export, export$reporter_iso), as.matrix)
```

A matrix can hold data of only one type in it. Since you have characters as well as numbers in your data all the data is transformed to character.